# Angularjs: Modify order of CRUD operations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, post, get

i have this function:

```
// Check if the object alredy exists. 
// If exists, the object it's deleted and created again.

save: function(url, obj, errors) {
   this.get(url, obj);
   this.create(url, obj, errors);
};
```

But no matter the order i call get and create. POST it's always executed first. There's some way to avoid that? You can see the [full code here](http://pastebin.com/GUHibvBk)

[image]

[SOLUTION](http://pastebin.com/6Yr4rpFR) (Thanks Hatsjoem!):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of promises (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Or simply by putting the create in the get.success callback.

Comment: I implemented the second option and worked like a charm, thank you! I was so close.